# *ngFor and filter pipe

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-pipe

What you see:

- list of the palette components that you can select
- the selected palette above the list
- the palette selected is not in the list anymore !WRONG!
- each time you pick a palette only the one you had selected before is being drawn which causes the list to expand with duplicates

What I did:

```
<ng-container
          *ngFor="let palette of palettes | exclude: currentPalette.name">
    <div class="span-6">
      <app-palette
              (click)="choosePalette(palette)"
              [palette]="palette"
              [name]="palette.name"
              [icon]="palette.icon.name">
      </app-palette>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

What actually worked:

```
<ng-container
          *ngFor="let palette of palettes">
    <div class="span-6" *ngIf="palette.name !== currentPalette.name">
      <!-- TODO pipe this to not show already selected -->
      <app-palette
              (click)="choosePalette(palette)"
              [palette]="palette"
              [name]="palette.name"
              [icon]="palette.icon.name">
      </app-palette>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

The 'exclude' pipe is just a filter (array.filter(p => p.name !== name));

When i debug the entire thing, it shows to me that everything is being processed just fine but only the component that should show up is being redrawn, but the rest stays along with the item that should disappear. This causes items it duplicate and floods the list.

How can I do it with a pipe? Or where was I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it. It wasn't a problem with a pipe it was a problem with rendering DOM elements.

app-palette has [ngStyle] directive that references object like this:

```
[ngStyle]=palette.foregound
```

just change every reference to:

```
[ngStyle]=palette?.foreground
```

Voila!